# What is 'tag' of tabItem in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I'm beginner of SwiftUI

I recently learning SwiftUI with Youtube Lecture

In TabView part,

```
TabView {
     myView(titleText: "프로필", bgColor: Color.blue) // it's just View I made
                 .tabItem { 
                     Image(systemName : "person.crop.circle.fill")
                     Text("프로필")
                 }.tag(2) // <- I'm wondering about this 'tag'
}
```

I'm wondering what does 'tag(_)' do in tabItem

thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for selection tracking

```
@State private var selected: Int = 0   // by default `first` tab, or any you want

TabView(selection: $selected) {
     myView(titleText: "프로필", bgColor: Color.blue) // it's just View I made
                 .tabItem { 
                     Image(systemName : "person.crop.circle.fill")
                     Text("프로필")
                 }.tag(2) // <- I'm wondering about this 'tag'
}
```

so you can track when `selected` is modified, say by `onChange(of:` or change selection programmatically in any action, say

```
Button("프로필") { selected = 2 }
```